# What does "foo does not contain a definition for 'bar'..." mean?

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I have add MIDI.dll into assembly property, I new to C# and following an example from MIDI.dot.net and got this error on `device.Spec`, what it mean by Midi.InputDevice does not contain a definition for 'spec' and no extension method 'spec' accepting a first argument of type Midi.InputDevice could not be found (are you missing a using directive...)?

My `using MIDI` is exist on top and I use MonoDevelop IDE.

```
public override void Run()

        {

            // Print a table of the input device names, or "No input devices" if there are none.

            if (InputDevice.InstalledDevices.Count == 0)

            {

                Console.WriteLine("No input devices.");

            }

            else

            {

                Console.WriteLine("Input Devices:");

                foreach (InputDevice device in InputDevice.InstalledDevices)

                {

                    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", device.Spec);

                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine();



            // Print a table of the output device names, or "No output devices" if there are none.

            if (OutputDevice.InstalledDevices.Count == 0)

            {

                Console.WriteLine("No output devices.");

            }

            else

            {
```

Comment: Where is that MIDI dll coming from? The error basically means that your input device does not have a property names `Spec`. Are you sure such a property exists?

Comment: Rebuild midi.dll, the version you are using appears outdated.  Source is here: http://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/source/browse/trunk/Midi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have your code written, I would expect Spec to be a Property of InputDevice.

According to the error message you're getting, that is not the case. There is no member named Spec on the type InputDevice.

Looking at the documentation here: [InputDevice Class](http://midi-dot-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Midi/docs/Midi~Midi.InputDevice.html) it definitely looks like that should be a valid Property. In your example, you have `Spec` upper cased but in the error message you provide, it is lower case. My guess is that it is lower case in your real code.

C# is case sensitive so that is probably why you are getting the error.

Comment: The code is in fact this sample: http://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/source/browse/trunk/ConsoleDemo/Example01.cs

Comment: 0xA3 - That's the example that got pasted, yes. Look at the OP's error though. It clearly says 'spec' throughout which leads me to believe there's a simple case issue in their code (which means it probably wasn't copy/pasted).

Answer (score 0):

replace 'Spec' by 'Name' and it will work perfectly !

Comment: These appear to be two different things.